# Vue.js - Friendly syntax without compilation templates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js is ideal library for my case, but I use it on non-SPA page.

Is there a way to bypass syntax `v-bind:click`? I would like the attributes starts from `data-v-*` and don't contains `:`.

**My solution (based on accepted answer):**

It looks like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) will not pass the exam here.
[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) proved to be the ideal library for friendly SEO html syntax without compilation templates.

Comment: is @click not pretty enough? :)

Comment: Can you give an example? Our clients have different seo companies, some require a w3c validator test. "v-bind:click" is not compatible with xml becouse of clon.

Comment: just saying @click is a shorthand for v-bind:click

Comment: U can use short form https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see something you can do. But "@" is also not compatible.

Comment: @Jarek: Maybe an attempt to convince the customer to avoid religiously following certain requirements (like satisfying the w3c validator) could be beneficial for both parties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `script` templates to "hide" your Vue-HTML from the validator. The following validates as HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
<script id="some-template" type="text/template">
  <div v-model="foo" v-bind:click="dontCare">Whatever</div>
</script>
<some-template id="app"></some-template>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not as much of a cheat as it might seem, since Vue-HTML **is not** HTML, but is in fact a template used for generating HTML (or, I think more accurately, for generating the DOM). But it is a complete cheat in the sense that the generated HTML is never subjected to the validator. :)

Alternatively, you could look at using [Knockout](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), which uses pure HTML5 (what you write is what is delivered to the browser). It is not as performant as Vue, but it is an MVVM framework.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: No.

I don't think there is a way to change the templating of Vue. The generated HTML shipped to user will be valid, because modifiers (v-for, v-bind, etc.) will be stripped of your HTML. Framework like Angular, for example, does not strip the multiple "ng-*" properties. For instance, you could write:

```
<div v-if="model.length" />
```

The resulting html will be:

```
<div />
```

Which is valid and compatible with any W3C validator.

Comment: I know this, but I can't compile html.

Comment: @Jarek well, sorry, I don't think VueJS can fit your w3c validation needs. SEO companies should validate outputted HTML, in my opinion.